# Unexpected behaviour of rand() in MySQL

Tags: random, mariadb

I encountered a very weird result while trying to filter my data using `RAND()` function.
Suppose i have a table filled with some data:

```
CREATE TABLE `status_log` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`rank` int(11) DEFAULT 50,
)
```

Then i do the following simple select:

```
select id,rank as rank,(rand()*100) as thres 
from status_log 
where rank = 50
```

and have a clear and expected output:

```
<...skip...>
| 6575476 |   50 |     34.51090244065123 |
| 6575511 |   50 |     67.84258230388404 |
| 6575589 |   50 |     35.68020727083106 |
| 6575644 |   50 |     74.87329251586766 |
| 6575723 |   50 |     67.32584384020961 |
| 6575771 |   50 |    12.009344726809621 |
| 6575863 |   50 |     58.06919518678374 |
+---------+------+-----------------------+
66169 rows in set (2.502 sec).
```

So, i generate some random data from 0 to 100 and join each result to the table, around 66000 results in total.

Then i want only a (random) part of the data to be shown. It doesn't have any purpose for production, by the way, it's just some artificial test, so let's not discuss it.

```
select * 
from (
    select id,rank as rank,(rand()*100) as thres   
    from status_log 
    where rank = 50) t 
where thres>rank 
order by thres;
```

After that i get the following:

```
<...skip...>
| 4396732 |   50 |  99.97966075314177 |
| 4001782 |   50 |  99.98002871869134 |
| 1788580 |   50 |  99.98064143581375 |
| 5300286 |   50 |  99.98275954274717 |
|  146401 |   50 |  99.98552389441573 |
| 4744748 |   50 |  99.98644758014609 |
+---------+------+--------------------+
16449 rows in set (2.188 sec)
```

It's obvious that for the mean of `50` the expected number of results should be around **33000** out of total **66000**. So it seems that the distribution of `rand()` is biased, correct?

Let's then change `>` to `<`:

```
select * 
from (
    select id,rank as rank,(rand()*100) as thres 
    from status_log 
    where rank = 50) t 
where thres<rank 
order by thres;
```

```
<...skip...>
| 4653786 |   50 |    49.98035016467827 |
| 6041489 |   50 |   49.980370281245904 |
| 5064204 |   50 |   49.989308742796354 |
| 1699741 |   50 |   49.991373205549436 |
| 3234039 |   50 |    49.99390454030959 |
|  806791 |   50 |    49.99575274996064 |
| 3713581 |   50 |    49.99814410693771 |
+---------+------+----------------------+
16562 rows in set (2.373 sec)
```

Again **16000**! So not the half but the quarter of all results is shown!
It seems that the output of `rand()` inside the brackets is somehow influenced with the expression outside them. How is this possible?

I can also union it:

```
select * from (select id,rank as rank,(rand()*100) as thres from status_log where rank = 50) t where thres<50
UNION ALL
select * from (select id,rank as rank,(rand()*100) as thres from status_log where rank = 50) t where thres>=50;
```

The expected number of results has to be somewhere **around 66000**, but it returns only **33000** or so.

I observe this behavior only when `rand()` is non-deterministic and is generated dynamically each time. If i do `...select id,rank as rank,(rand(id)*100)...` (i.e. make the output of rand() dependent of id), i start getting the expected number of results (**33000**-ish). The same happens if i precalculate and fill a temporary field in the table.

I also tried making the filtering with `rank=30`, and the results were `~6000` and `~32000` for `<` and `>` respectively.

Version `10.5.8-MariaDB-3`, `InnoDB`

Comment: I think this is actually due to some optimizations that it does between the subquery and the condition in the main query. Try creating a temporary table holding the result of the subquery, then select from that.

Comment: I consider this workaround (together with some other ideas), but before i would like to be sure that there is no native fix for that and that it's definitely not a bug i can report about.

Comment: I can confirm that the temporary table works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a single query with `HAVING` instead of a subquery with `WHERE` in the main query seems to work around it.

```
select id,rank as rank,(rand()*100) as thres   
from status_log 
where rank = 50
having thres > rank
order by thres
```

This appears to be this bug:

[RAND() evaluated and filtered twice with subquery](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-23066)

Comment: Indeed `HAVING` is working, thanks. But what is the nature of the original fail? Should it be reported as a bug?

Comment: It seems like a bug to me, no harm in reporting it.

Comment: I found it in their bug database.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help!